# Sagepay Pay Now Button - Visual Studio Application

Tags: visual-studio, payment-gateway, opayo

I already use Sage Line50 (accounts application) which has a very convenient Pay Now button.

As I understand it, you highlight a customer record in Sage Line50 and click Pay Now. A simple form appears into which you put the amount that you are requesting the customer to pay. The form has a Copy Link button which you then click.

You then paste this link into an email, send to the customer, customer clicks it and arrives on the Sagepay website where they are taken through the payment process.

Sagepay describes the process as: This link contains all the transaction information in a format that the Sage Pay gateway can understand.  When the customer clicks ‘Pay Now’ the encrypted contents of that field are POSTed to the Sage Pay gateway and the customer redirected to the hosted Sage Pay payment page.

So Sage Line50 Pay Now functionality is what I want (my developer) to replicate in the Visual Studio application he is working on for me.

My question is either how she he go about this OR can I pay anyone out there to do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Form protocol (easily googleable) - this will create a standalone link which redirects your customer to Sage Pay.